# Formatting an element within a Listbox element in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, listboxitem

Just want to ask if there is a way to format an element inside a listbox element in Tkinter.

In this sample code, I wish to change the color of the numbers (the first element of the listbox elements) to blue. I tried itemconfig but will only work for an entire element. Hope you can help me. Thank you very much!

```
from tkinter import *

sample_list = [(1, "Faith"), (2, "Hope"), (3, "Love")]

class Database(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        scrollbarList=Scrollbar(self)
        scrollbarList.pack(side = RIGHT)

        studentlist = Listbox(self, yscrollcommand=scrollbarList.set)
        studentlist.pack(side = LEFT)
        scrollbarList.config(command= studentlist.yview)

        for row in sample_list: studentlist.insert(END,row)
    
    
root = Tk()
database_window = Database(root)
database_window.pack(side="top")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is not possible with a `Listbox`, only the `Text` widget allows for using different colors for different parts of the text on the same line. If you want colored numbers, you will have to display them outside of the listbox.

Comment: @j_4321 ah ok, just what I thought as well when I tried itemconfig. Thank you